# cannot change page in backbone app by typing address in browser

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I'm writing a Backbone app where I enabled push state in the router

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true});
```

If I click a link [get beer](/beer) on the homepage to go to another page-- at localhost:8080/beer--, everything works as desired. However, if I type `localhost:8080/beer` in the browser, I don't get the Backbone page for the Beer route, but rather the template rendered by the server (in this case, a golang backend) or, if there isn't one, a 404 message. This makes the app basically useless as I can't count on users only clicking links and not typing addresses in the browser. Is it possible to navigate to different pages of a Backbone app that uses push state by typing the address in the browser and, if so, how?

Comment: did you configure your backend router to map **all**  URLs to the html page that renders your app?

Comment: @UziKilon Shouldn't your comment be your an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure your backend router to map all URLs that are mapped to in your Backbone router to the html page that renders your app

Comment: Thanks, not sure how to do this in Go lang, I'll have to figure it out and try it before I can accept your answer

Comment: this renders my app `http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./publica/")))` so, trying your suggestion, I did this, but it doesn't work (i.e. same problem) `http.Handle("/beer", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./publica/index.html")))`

Comment: if possible, please show me an example from any backend that you use (doesn't have to be golang)

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil What do you mean by didn't work? Please be more specific in terms of what actually happened and any error messages, it looks like you're doing the right thing.

Comment: @JuanMendes If I type `localhost:8080/beer`in the browser, I get a `404` (rendered by the server), even though my backend is configured (I believe) to map the `/beer`to the index page that renders my app, i.e. `http.Handle("/beer", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./publica/index.html")))`

Comment: If it was mapped correctly, you wouldn't get a 404. 404 is a server error indicating it couldn't find a resource mapped the requested URL.

Comment: I didn't map it correctly. Have to use ServeFile with Go to serve a single file